# Chrome not remembering Google Account login

Tags: google-chrome

On my home pc running Chrome 65.0.3325.181, when starting chrome it asks to login to a google account.

I log in, setup everything. Next time I start chrome, it shows the exact same screen as the first time in the beginning, asking to log in.

I tried creating a new "Person", reinstalling, all sorts of things. Nothing seems to work.

What should I do to fix this?
One thing to mention, the account is not @gmail.com, but from a school using gapps. (so someaccountname@someschool.com).

This should work right?